# Query inserting only top 100 rows

Tags: sql-server

I am using the following query.
But, it just transfers the top 1000 rows, thats it. Even though I have more rows.
If I remove the `where not exists` clause, I get full data. Can you let me know where am I wrong ?

```
DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 1000
DECLARE @Counter INT = 0
DECLARE @TableCount INT = 0
set @TableCount = (select count(*) from Table2)

while @Counter < (@TableCount/@BatchSize+1)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Table1 
    SELECT * FROM Table2 MH
    inner join Table3 M
    on MH.Mid = M.Mid
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (  
        SELECT * FROM Table1
        where MH.otherid = M.otherid
    )   
    order by id OFFSET (@BatchSize * @Counter)ROWS FETCH NEXT @Batchsize ROWS ONLY;
    SET @Counter=@Counter+1

END
```

Why is it just inserting top 1000 rows ?

Comment: And *why* are you executing the query this way? Why not simply issue the full query in one go?

Comment: Since the question as it stands "why is it just inserting top 1000 rows" is no longer valid because of a simple mistake (the original form of the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause) then I vote to close this question.

Comment: I have millions of data and I do not want to lock the full table

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  
    SELECT 1 FROM Table1
)
```

will only evaluate to true for the first batch of inserts. After that, there are records in the target table, the WHERE clause evaluates to false, so no further inserts happen.

Comment: I updated the query, Now, I just get every alternating 1000 rows.

Comment: Please don't change the question as you go. That invalidates some previous answers.

Comment: The question still remains that I am not getting all the rows, it is either getting top or half the rows.

Answer (score 0):

How many rows are in Table2?  Your second loop is going to produce the WHILE condition of `(1 < (TableCount / 1001)` if you're Table Count is more than 1001 rows, it will jump out after the first loop.

Comment: Ahhh, this might be an issue but I like @Eric J.'s answer as well; good point!

Comment: I updated the query, Now, I just get every alternating 1000 rows.

Comment: Please don't post a moving target question. If you haven't thought through or experimented enough to know exactly what to ask for, do that first, then post your question and await the answers. If at this point you find other things to experiment with, do that and then come back and post *a new* question. Don't edit the question such that the current answers are invalidated. The question you originally had was answered. That should be it. If you feel this would pollute SO with lots of similar questions, then good, that means you haven't worked with the question enough. Do that first.

Comment: The question still remains that I am not getting all the rows, it is either getting top or half the rows.

Comment: Yes, but "why is it only inserting 1000 rows" is your question. That question was answered. It still is. Please do a *full* edit of your question then, but bear in mind what I just said, don't edit the question every time you discover that you haven't thought through the question or the code, or have debugged enough.

Comment: It looks like there's still a problem with your EXISTS clause.  You're `SELECTING * FROM Table1 WHERE Table2.otherid = Table3.otherid`. Neither of the statements in your WHERE clause join back to Table1, which I don't think is what you're trying to accomplish.  You're trying to verify if the row you're looking at ALREADY exists in Table1; try to find a way to relate your EXISTS() check to Table1.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 1000
DECLARE @Counter INT = 0
--DECLARE @TableCount INT = 0
--set @TableCount = (select count(*) from Table2)
declare @rows int = 1
while @rows>0--@Counter < (@TableCount/@BatchSize+1)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Table1 
    SELECT * FROM Table2 MH
    inner join Table3 M
    on MH.Mid = M.Mid
    --if you want non-existing
    left join table1 t on t.field = M.field
    where t.field is null
    -- end if you want
    --WHERE NOT EXISTS (  --not exists WHAT?
    --    SELECT 1 FROM Table1
    --)   
    order by id OFFSET (@BatchSize * @Counter) ROWS FETCH NEXT @Batchsize ROWS ONLY;
    --SET @Counter=@Counter+1
    select @rows = @@rowcount, @counter = @counter + 1 
END
```